# Commit in git with different user

Tags: git, github, git-commit

I am using git in a enterprise server and git has a specific user configured in config files. My user in git has permission to make changes in git repository, but I would like to be able to do git commit with my user because I don't know the password of configured user.

How can I do that? For example, I can do a pull with next command:

```
git pull https://myusername@github.com/projectfolder/projectname.git master
```

Thanks beforehand.
Mike.

Answer (score 0):

git commit --author="author@mail.com" -m "Comment"